# Como colocar os valores de uma coluna do db em um array?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Eu tenho uma tabela, a qual esta escrita abaixo. Busy é a parte que eu irei mexer. o valor de busy ficará alterando de acordo com o programa de 0 a 1, dependendo se estiver ocupado ou nao. Preciso carregar esse valores em um array, como posso fazer isso ?

```
String QUERY_COLUNA = "CREATE TABLE " + TABELA_SLOT + "(" +
    COLUNA_CODIGO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," +
    COLUNA_BUSY + " INTEGER )";

db.execSQL(QUERY_COLUNA);

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABELA_SLOT + "(BUSY) VALUES ('0')");
```

Comment: Seria interessante colocar na sua pergunta o que você já fez. Isso facilitará para quem vai responder.

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta! Você deseja consultar o valor do banco de dados e inserir em um Array?